# How do I have Geonames api work with https?

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, geonames

I'm sending ajax requests to [Geonames Search api](https://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html). 
It works pretty well on http protocol.

But when I switch to https (both my own server and the api requests), my requests are blocked by the browser: Geonames https certificate seems to be invalid.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Oh! I coudn't find the response on Stackoverflow. But is was [on Geonames forum](http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/35422.page) already:

Https requests should be sent to `secure.geonames.org` instead of `api.geonames.org`. That's it!